# Getting data from another form into dataGridView

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I am working on an account generator and I need help making my accounts appear into a `dataGridView` in another form. My code is this right now. I don't know how I can put my accounts into a `dataGridView`.

**This is the Form I have:**

[image]

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = richTextBox2.Text;
        string password = richTextBox1.Text;
        for (var currentAccount = 0; currentAccount < (Int32.TryParse(out)).richTextBox4.Text; currentAccount++)
        {
        }

        List<string> Firstnames = new List<string>();
        Firstnames.Add("James");
        Firstnames.Add("Jakob");
        Firstnames.Add("Jacob");
        Firstnames.Add("Jonathan");
        Firstnames.Add("Albert");
        Firstnames.Add("Calvin");
        Firstnames.Add("Kyle");
        Firstnames.Add("Christopher");
        Firstnames.Add("Jeremy");
        Firstnames.Add("Ari");
        Firstnames.Add("Maximus");
        Firstnames.Add("Jerry");
        Firstnames.Add("Eric");
        Firstnames.Add("Trey");
        Firstnames.Add("Brenden");
        Firstnames.Add("Sean");
        Firstnames.Add("Timmothy");
        Firstnames.Add("Harris");
        Firstnames.Add("Matthew");
        Firstnames.Add("Michael");
        Firstnames.Add("Ching");
        Firstnames.Add("Alexander");

        Random rand = new Random();
        int x = rand.Next(0, Firstnames.Count);

        List<string> Lastnames = new List<string>();
        Lastnames.Add("Hampton");
        Lastnames.Add("Green");
        Lastnames.Add("Doe");
        Lastnames.Add("Ching");
        Lastnames.Add("Chong");
        Lastnames.Add("Albertson");
        Lastnames.Add("Ringel");
        Lastnames.Add("Alerstein");
        Lastnames.Add("Zion");
        Lastnames.Add("Stein");
        Lastnames.Add("Stine");
        Lastnames.Add("Elzed");
        Lastnames.Add("Jackson");
        Lastnames.Add("Cooperberg");
        Lastnames.Add("Charman");
        Lastnames.Add("Calberg");
        Lastnames.Add("Dorfmanberg");

        int y = rand.Next(0, Lastnames.Count);

        List<string> passwords = new List<string>();
        passwords.Add("richTextBox1_TextChanged");

        List<string> screenName = new List<string>();
        screenName.Add("");

        List<string> emails = new List<string>();
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+1209943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+16329943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+56329943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+9943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+123456329943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+156329943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+1239943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+123456329943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+1234563292943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+12345603");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+1234563299");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+13001");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+12990-3");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+99103z");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+1x3");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+1623bdsjaw");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+99jsd943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+12345938urfv3");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+ejfj9943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+1234rmd43");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+dmmd29943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+123456kiuj943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+12i8839291");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+123bfbdba3");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+123absna43");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+1234ababsba9943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+1asa943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+989283");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+1234jfn9943");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+kd13jd23");
        emails.Add("richTextBox2_TextChanged+938478du");


        List<string> birthmonth = new List<string>();
        birthmonth.Add("1");
        birthmonth.Add("2");
        birthmonth.Add("3");
        birthmonth.Add("4");
        birthmonth.Add("5");
        birthmonth.Add("6");
        birthmonth.Add("7");
        birthmonth.Add("8");
        birthmonth.Add("9");
        birthmonth.Add("10");
        birthmonth.Add("11");
        birthmonth.Add("12");
        int z = rand.Next(0, birthmonth.Count);

        List<string> birthday = new List<string>();
        birthday.Add("13");
        birthday.Add("10");
        birthday.Add("9");
        birthday.Add("7");
        birthday.Add("30");
        birthday.Add("20");
        birthday.Add("21");
        birthday.Add("3");
        birthday.Add("2");
        birthday.Add("1");
        birthday.Add("19");
        birthday.Add("18");
        birthday.Add("15");
        birthday.Add("11");
        birthday.Add("22");
        birthday.Add("26");
        birthday.Add("27");
        birthday.Add("29");
        int a = rand.Next(0, birthday.Count);

        List<string> birthyear = new List<string>();
        birthyear.Add("1985");
        birthyear.Add("1986");
        birthyear.Add("1987");
        birthyear.Add("1988");
        birthyear.Add("1989");
        birthyear.Add("1990");
        birthyear.Add("1991");
        birthyear.Add("1992");
        birthyear.Add("1993");
        birthyear.Add("1994");
        birthyear.Add("1995");
        birthyear.Add("1984");
        birthyear.Add("1983");
        birthyear.Add("1982");
        birthyear.Add("1981");
        int b = rand.Next(0, birthyear.Count);

        List<string> postalcode = new List<string>();
        postalcode.Add("richTextBox5_TextChanged");

        List<string> gender = new List<string>();
        gender.Add("male");

        string first = Firstnames[x];
        String last = Lastnames[y];

        comboBox1.FindStringExact("nike_us"); webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("exp-register-firstName").SetAttribute("value", "firstnames");
        comboBox1.FindStringExact("nike_us"); webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("exp-register-lastName").SetAttribute("value", "lastnames");
        comboBox1.FindStringExact("nike_us"); webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("exp-register-email").SetAttribute("value", "emails");
        comboBox1.FindStringExact("nike_us"); webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("exp-register-password").SetAttribute("value", "passwords");
        comboBox1.FindStringExact("nike_us"); webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("exp-register-passwordConfirm").SetAttribute("value", "passwords");
        comboBox1.FindStringExact("nike_us"); webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("exp-register-screenName").SetAttribute("value", "screenName");
        comboBox1.FindStringExact("nike_US"); webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("exp-register-dob-month").SetAttribute("value", "birthmonth");
        comboBox1.FindStringExact("nike_us"); webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("exp-register-dob-day").SetAttribute("value", "birthday");
        comboBox1.FindStringExact("nike_us"); webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("exp-register-dob-year").SetAttribute("value", "birthyear");
        comboBox1.FindStringExact("nike_us"); webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("exp-register-postalCode").SetAttribute("value", "postalcode");
        comboBox1.FindStringExact("nike_us"); webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("exp-register-gender-male").SetAttribute("value", "gender");
        comboBox1.FindStringExact("nike_us"); webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sign_up").InvokeMember("click");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new form constructor for the child form and in the child form setup properties for what needs to be passed. Below shows an overload new constructor with one parameter and as needed repeat this pattern.

**Please note** there are other methods, this is but one of them.
**Second note**: I used a ListBox to keep it simple and realize you have a DataGridView.

**Main form**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> Firstnames = new List<string>();
        Firstnames.Add("James");
        Firstnames.Add("Jakob");
        Firstnames.Add("Jacob");
        Firstnames.Add("Jonathan");
        Firstnames.Add("Albert");
        Firstnames.Add("Calvin");
        Firstnames.Add("Kyle");
        Firstnames.Add("Christopher");
        Firstnames.Add("Jeremy");
        Firstnames.Add("Ari");
        Firstnames.Add("Maximus");
        Firstnames.Add("Jerry");
        Firstnames.Add("Eric");
        Firstnames.Add("Trey");
        Firstnames.Add("Brenden");
        Firstnames.Add("Sean");
        Firstnames.Add("Timmothy");
        Firstnames.Add("Harris");
        Firstnames.Add("Matthew");
        Firstnames.Add("Michael");
        Firstnames.Add("Ching");
        Firstnames.Add("Alexander");

        Form2 f = new Form2(Firstnames);

        try
        {
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
        finally
        {
            f.Dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

**Child form** with a ListBox, a property for first names list.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public List<string> FirstNames { get; set; }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Form2(List<string> firstNames)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FirstNames = firstNames;
        this.Shown += Form2_Shown;
    }

    private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = this.FirstNames;
    }
}
```